# Как правильно выполнить команду grep

Tags: linux, grep

Начал изучать grep. Взял задание "Вывести все слова которые начинаются на буквы aA,zZ,cC,dD и заканчиваются буков y. За пару часов перелопатил кучу сайтов, смог только написать первую часть, которая находить первые буквы, а как написать чтобы находило слова по заглавным буквам + последней (y) я ХЗ((( 
P.S посоветуйте хороший туториал для новичков.

```
grep '^[aA|zZ|cC|dD]
```

Comment: Как-то так: `grep -o '^[aAzZcCdD][^[:space:]]*y[^a-zA-Z]'`. Не надо ничего переворачивать, хозяин помещения будет недоволен, почитайте просто `man 7 regex`.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o '^[aAzZcCdD][^[:space:]]*y'
```

Comment: Это не подойдет как ответ, может быть выбрана часть слова до `y`, К примеру часть слова `dayson` подойдет к вашему шаблону и вернет `day` как совпадение. В примере @0andriy это учитывается, но я бы немного добавил бы от себя: `grep -oP '^[aAzZcCdD][^[:space:]]*y(?=[^A-Za-z]|$)'` - Ключ -P расширенные регулярные выражения от perl, `(?=[^A-Za-z]|$)` Проверяем условие без захвата, что y находится в конце строки, либо за ним нет буквенного символа.